# How to Disable Selection and Right Click wit HTAccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Is there a way available to disable viewing source, selection and right click with .htaccess file?

I have tried Googling for solutions, but could not find any reference to it thus far.

Comment: Seems like you look at this from the wrong angle ... Look at it this way: you publish your html documents. If you publish them, then it is up to the client to decide what to do with them, how to use them. You should actually not have any reason to prevent the client from any action. If that is the case, then you typically made a mistake in your architecture and expose private things in a location where they do not belong. Then _that_ is what you need to change. In other words: your setup needs to be robust against all actions a client desires to perform - if it is not, then change that.

Answer (score 1):

No. `.htaccess` is not the correct tool for the job. `.htaccess` files are a server configuration file, it cannot do anything to affect how a user interacts with the website/browser UI - for that you would need JavaScript.

You can't prevent the user from viewing the HTML source of the webpage. (Without blocking all access to the webpage!)

I would avoid trying to block the "right click". This will only annoy users and deliver a bad UX. The user can always circumvent any "right click" restrictions anyway.

Comment: Hello. The point is that I do not care what will users do on their side. To me, it is only important to copy-protect the Web Site's content and not to think about how much I. T.-savvy the user/the visitor is. The important thing is that the Web Site's content be well-protected/obfuscated in order not to be read by humans. I hope I at least for a little brought closer to what I need. I already did obfuscation(s) without any problems: it was well-read by Web Browsers, but well-hidden for humans. I would still like to wait for a few more days, merely to see if any one else will answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable view source. You can disable right-click, but that won't stop anyone viewing the website code via developer tools.

You can also disable hotlinking - this stops people 'hotlinking' to your images
Go to the .htaccess file and add this command:

```
#disable hotlinking of images with forbidden or custom image option 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www.)?my-website.com/.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule .(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ - [F]
```

Change the phrase “my-website.com” to the actual address for your website that you wish to protect.